# Array Casting Issue

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code:

```
String []d=new String[]{"y","z"};
Object []ab=d;
d=(String[]) ab;
System.out.println(d[0]);
System.out.println(ab[0]);
```

as expected returns *y* twice

But the following code throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException` (here `fileList` is an `ArrayList<File>` object)

```
File[] loadedFiles=new File[fileList.size()];
Object[] toArray = fileList.toArray();
loadedFiles=(File[]) toArray;
System.out.println(toArray[0]);
System.out.println(loadedFiles[0]);
```

While the following doesn't throw anything:

```
loadedFiles=fileList.toArray(new File[0]);
```

[Javadoc 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) says (about `toArray()`):

> The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are maintained by this collection. (In other words, this method must allocate a new array even if this collection is backed by an array). The caller is thus free to modify the returned array.

So why can't I modify the array type by casting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So why can't I modify the array type by casting?

Casting *never* changes the type of an actual object. It just checks that the reference in question is a reference to an object of an appropriate type, and lets you use that reference "as" the new type.

Now the array that the value of `toArray` refers to is an `Object[]`, not a `File[]`. You can verify this yourself by printing out `toArray.getClass()`. Therefore you can't cast it to a `File[]`.

You can call an overload which *takes* an array, at which point it will do the right thing:

```
Object[] toArray = fileList.toArray(new File[0]);
```

At that point, `toArray` will refer to an instance of `File[]`, so when you cast it later, all is well.

Comment: Jon, that principle called `Contravariant` ?

Comment: @OrelEraki: No, not really. Reference type array objects themselves are *covariant* - so a `String[]` referenced can be assigned to an `Object[]` variable. Is that what you were thinking of?